# Getting Error building flutter project in Xcode

Tags: xcode, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbL2B.png)

ios/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_place_picker-1.0.1/lib/src/components/prediction_tile.dart:29:51: Error:
The getter 'title' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
- 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart'
('ios/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'title'.
final textColor = Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.color;
^^^^^

Failed to package /Users/ABC/Documents/myApp-master.

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system

note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
```

Could not build the application for the

Tried solution

1. Maintaining same ios deployment version in podfile and target
2. Clean build, reinstalling pod
3. Using flutter version 2.5.3
4. Xcode version 13.2.1

Comment: Hi there! :) Looks like this is Your first question, so I will suggest some format changes in the future.
You should have started Your question with the current setup, so "I am using this library, here is my code, and this is what happens". You only shared the last part of the setup, which makes it harder for people to answer.
In general, if You want Your questions to be answered as soon as possible, try asking the question in such a way that writing a response is easy.
In this particular case, I saw in the error log that You're using the google_maps_place_picker package. So I went to their re

Answer (score 0):

So clean the folder...
Try invalidating cache/restart Android studio, make sure Xcode is closed
Build it again and try 1-2

1- Try targeting a diff simulator, does it work fine on Android?
2- By diff simulator, I also mean a diff IOS variant too.

Is this how you are cleaning the file?
`$ cd ios/ $ pod clean $ pod install`

Comment: it's working fine for android on a windows machine. I was trying to run it on mac using Xcode only for ios. And yes I am following the commands for cleaning.